# How to use org.owasp.encoder.Encode in Java?

Tags: java, owasp, veracode

```
public static void sendEmail(String to, String cc, String subject, String content) throws IOException {
    LOG.info(ESAPIValidation.sanitizeParam((String.format("EmailUtil.sendEMail() \n To: %s\n Subjet: %s \n  Content: %s", to, subject, content))));
    String host = ApplicationUtil.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.AL_WS_MAIL_HOST);
    String port = ApplicationUtil.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.AL_WS_MAIL_PORT);
    String from = ApplicationUtil.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.AL_WS_MAIL_FROM);
    String defaultToAdd = ApplicationUtil.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.AL_WS_DEFAULT_MAIL);
    String emailSystemPrefix = ApplicationUtil.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.EMAIL_PREFIX);

    if (StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(emailSystemPrefix)) {
        emailSystemPrefix = "";
    } else {
        emailSystemPrefix =  emailSystemPrefix  + " - "; 
    }

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        addToList(message, to);
        
        addCCList(message, cc);
        if(cc == null || (cc != null && !cc.equals(defaultToAdd)))
        addCCList(message, defaultToAdd);

        content = addFooter(content);
        message.setSubject(emailSystemPrefix + subject);
        message.setContent(content.replace("textarea", "div"), "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (AddressException addressException) {
        LOG.warn("EmailUtil.triggerDBFailureMail() AddressException ", addressException);
    } catch (MessagingException messageException) {
        LOG.warn("EmailUtil.triggerDBFailureMail() MessagingException ", messageException);
    }
}
```

Here in this code, I'm getting Veracode issue:

> Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences('CRLF Injection')(CWE ID 93)

on

```
message.setSubject(emailSystemPrefix + subject);
```

I'm trying to use `org.owasp.encoder.Encode` to resolve the same, but I do not know the usage of `Encode` class. Can anybody please brief about implementation of `Encode` class, where is it used, what is resolved with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about `Encode` class in [docs](https://owasp.org/owasp-java-encoder/encoder/apidocs/org/owasp/encoder/Encode.html)

> Encode -- fluent interface for contextual encoding.
>
> There are two versions of each contextual encoding method. The first takes a String argument and returns the encoded version as a String. The second version writes the encoded version directly to a Writer.
>
> Please make sure to read and understand the context that the method encodes for. Encoding for the incorrect context will likely lead to exposing a cross-site scripting vulnerability.

And [CRLF Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/CRLF_Injection)

> The term CRLF refers to Carriage Return (ASCII 13, \r) Line Feed (ASCII 10, \n). They’re used to note the termination of a line, however, dealt with differently in today’s popular Operating Systems. For example: in Windows both a CR and LF are required to note the end of a line, whereas in Linux/UNIX a LF is only required. In the HTTP protocol, the CR-LF sequence is always used to terminate a line.
>
> A CRLF Injection attack occurs when a user manages to submit a CRLF into an application. This is most commonly done by modifying an HTTP parameter or URL.